# Python-how to send commands to existing shell?

Tags: python, shell, cmd, ironpython

I have a shell that is opened and I'm running some commands there.
my python file should also run 1 command there
How can I do it without opening this shell again ? (I want to use the already opened one)
thanks a lot!

editing :
It's an .exe that I compiled and i'm opening and running some "init" functions.
I want my python script for example to to something like:
"func(path to the .exe, commans to execute)"
and when using the path - it will use the exsiting .exe

Comment: Which OS?  What sort of shell?

Comment: Could you clarify on what you mean?  Are you typing commands into this window? Do you want your python script to respond based on a command? or also be issuing commands?

Comment: [What have your tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the subprocess module:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("shell commands go in here")
```

This will execute shell commands from within the location of your Python script.
Example:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["ping", "www.google.com"])
PING www.google.com (178.59.100.242) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from cache.google.com (178.59.100.242): icmp_req=1 ttl=54 time=19.1 ms
```